# Getting 'Out of memory!' error in very involved Perl script

Tags: perl

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232836/getting-specific-out-of-memory-message-when-running-very-involved-perl-script) a while ago on Ask Ubuntu and was directed to provide some code here, as it's probably an optimization problem. I've included the whole script.

The general goal is to go through roughly 7000 HTML files in a directory and parse specific information from them and export it to a text file as one line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Switch;
use strict;

use HTML::Query 'Query';

my $dir = '/home/mark/Documents/Perl/garchivesfiles/completeresults';

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Can't open $dir: $!";
my @files = map {"$dir/$_"} grep { $_ !~ /^\./ } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

my $total;

my %xlateNum2Text =  qw (0   January
                         1   Febuary
                         2   March
                         3   April
                         4   May
                         5   June
                         6   July
                         7   August
                         8   September
                         9   October
                         10  November
                         11  December                  
                       );


my $inc = 0;
foreach my $file (@files) {
    open FILE, $file;
    my $html = do { local $/; <FILE> };
    my $q = Query(text => $html);

    my @homescore = $q->query("span.homeScore");
    my @awayscore = $q->query("span.awayScore");
    my $singlehomescore = $homescore[0]->as_text();
    my $singleawayscore = $homescore[0]->as_text();

    my @hometeam = $q->query("table.teaminfo td.home span");
    my @awayteam = $q->query("table.teaminfo td.away span");
    my $singlehometeam = rightTeamName($hometeam[0]->as_text());
    my $singleawayteam = rightTeamName($awayteam[0]->as_text());


    my @homegoalstotal;
    my @awaygoalstotal;
    my @datearray;
    my @fixtureinfo;

    my @newhomegoals;
    my @newawaygoals;

    my @allinfogoals;

    if($singlehomescore ne "0" || $singleawayscore ne "0") {
        @homegoalstotal = $q->query("div.home ul li");
        @awaygoalstotal = $q->query("div.away ul li");
        my $i = 0;

        @datearray = $q->query("p.fixtureinfo span");
        my $finaldate = $datearray[0]->as_text();
        my @datecomponents = split(" ", $finaldate);
        my $mysqlyyyy = $datecomponents[3];
        my $mysqlmm = monthConvert($datecomponents[2]); 
        my $mysqldd = $datecomponents[1];

        my $mysqldate;

        if(length($mysqlmm) == 1) {
            $mysqlmm = "0".$mysqlmm;
        }

        if(length($mysqldd) == 1) {
            $mysqldd = "0".$mysqldd;
        }

        $mysqldate = $mysqlyyyy."-".$mysqlmm."-".$mysqldd;


        @fixtureinfo = $q->query("p.fixtureinfo");
        my $fixtureinfoinit = $fixtureinfo[0]->as_text();
        my @fixtureinfobrokenup = split(/ \| /, $fixtureinfoinit);
        my $fixtureinfostring = $fixtureinfobrokenup[1];

        foreach my $goal (@homegoalstotal) {
            my $tempmodifier = $goal->as_text();
            $tempmodifier =~ s/\)//g;
            my @tempcomponents = split(' \(', $tempmodifier);
            my $substitutetemp;
            my @extratimesplit;
            my $compositetime;

            if(index($tempcomponents[1], ",") != -1) {
                my @goaltimes = split('\,', $tempcomponents[1]);
                foreach my $individmultgoal (@goaltimes) {
                    $individmultgoal =~ s/Pen//g;
                    $individmultgoal =~ s/ //g;
                    if(index($individmultgoal, "OG") == -1) {
                        if(index($individmultgoal, "+") != -1) {
                            @extratimesplit = split('\+', $individmultgoal);
                            $compositetime = $extratimesplit[0];
                            push (@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents[0], $compositetime, "for:".$singlehometeam, $singleawayteam, $datecomponents[1], ,$datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, $extratimesplit[1]));
                            $i++;
                        } else {
                            push (@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents[0], $individmultgoal, "for:".$singlehometeam, $singleawayteam, $datecomponents[1], ,$datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, 0));
                            $i++;
                        }   
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $substitutetemp = $tempcomponents[1];
                $substitutetemp =~ s/Pen//g;
                $substitutetemp =~ s/ //g;
                if(index($substitutetemp, "OG") == -1) {
                    if(index($substitutetemp, "+") != -1) {
                        @extratimesplit = split('\+', $substitutetemp);
                        $compositetime = $extratimesplit[0];
                        push (@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents[0], $compositetime, "for:".$singlehometeam, $singleawayteam, $datecomponents[1], $datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, $extratimesplit[1]));
                        $i++;
                    } else {
                        push (@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents[0], $substitutetemp, "for:".$singlehometeam, $singleawayteam, $datecomponents[1], $datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, 0));
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach my $goal (@awaygoalstotal) {
            my $tempmodifier2 = $goal->as_text();
            $tempmodifier2 =~ s/\)//g;
            my @tempcomponents2 = split(' \(', $tempmodifier2);
            my $substitutetemp2;
            my @extratimesplit2;
            my $compositetime2;

            if(index($tempcomponents2[1], ",") != -1) {
                my @goaltimes2 = split('\,', $tempcomponents2[1]);
                foreach my $individmultgoal2 (@goaltimes2) {
                    $individmultgoal2 =~ s/Pen//g;
                    $individmultgoal2 =~ s/ //g;
                    if(index($individmultgoal2, "OG") == -1) {
                        if(index($individmultgoal2, "+") != -1) {
                            @extratimesplit2 = split('\+', $individmultgoal2);
                            $compositetime2 = $extratimesplit2[0];
                            push (@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents2[0], $compositetime2, "for:".$singleawayteam, $singlehometeam, $datecomponents[1], $datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, $extratimesplit2[1]));
                            $i++;
                        } else {
                            push (@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents2[0], $individmultgoal2, "for:".$singleawayteam, $singlehometeam, $datecomponents[1], $datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, 0));
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $substitutetemp2 = $tempcomponents2[1];
                $substitutetemp2 =~ s/Pen//g;
                $substitutetemp2 =~ s/ //g;
                if(index($substitutetemp2, "OG") == -1) {
                    if(index($substitutetemp2, "+") != -1) {
                        @extratimesplit2 = split('\+', $substitutetemp2);
                        $compositetime2 = $extratimesplit2[0];
                        push(@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents2[0], $compositetime2, "for:".$singleawayteam, $singlehometeam, $datecomponents[1], $datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, $extratimesplit2[1]));
                        $i++;
                    } else {
                        push(@{$allinfogoals[$i]}, ($tempcomponents2[0], $substitutetemp2, "for:".$singleawayteam, $singlehometeam, $datecomponents[1], $datecomponents[2], $datecomponents[3], $fixtureinfostring, "Barclays Premier League", monthConvert($datecomponents[2]), $mysqldate, 0));
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        @allinfogoals = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[12] <=> $b->[12] } @allinfogoals;

        open(GOALCSV, '>>goalcsv.txt');

        my $homegoalcount = 0;
        my $awaygoalcount = 0;

        foreach my $row(@allinfogoals){
           foreach my $val(@$row){
                if($val eq "for:".$singlehometeam) {
                    $homegoalcount++;
                    print GOALCSV "$val,".$homegoalcount.",".$awaygoalcount.",true,";
                    print "$val,".$homegoalcount.",".$awaygoalcount.",true,";
                } elsif($val eq "for:".$singleawayteam) {
                    $awaygoalcount++;
                    print GOALCSV "$val,".$awaygoalcount.",".$homegoalcount.",false,";
                    print "$val,".$awaygoalcount.",".$homegoalcount.",false,";
                } else {
                    print GOALCSV "$val,";
                    print "$val,";
                }
           }
           print GOALCSV "\n";
           print "\n";
        }
    }

}

sub rightTeamName{
    my $teamname = $_[0];

    switch($teamname) {
        case "Nott'm Forest" { return "Nottingham Forest" }
        case "QPR"  { return "Queens Park Rangers" }
        case "Southampton" { return "Southampton FC" }
        case "Norwich" { return "Norwich City" }
        case "Tottenham" { return "Tottenham Hotspur" }
        case "Leeds" { return "Leeds United" }
        case "Middlesbrough" { return "Middlesbrough FC" }
        case "Chelsea" { return "Chelsea FC" }
        case "Arsenal" { return "Arsenal FC" }
        case "Oldham" { return "Oldham Athletic" }
        case "Ipswich" { return "Ipswich Town" }
        case "Man Utd" { return "Manchester United" }
        case "Man City" { return "Manchester City" }
        case "Sheffield Wed" { return "Sheffield Wednesday" }
        case "Man City" { return "Manchester City" }
        case "Blackburn" { return "Blackburn Rovers" }
        case "Wimbledon" { return "AFC Wimbledon" }
        case "Liverpool" { return "Liverpool FC" }
        case "Coventry" { return "Coventry City" }
        else        { return $teamname }

    }
}

sub monthConvert{
        switch($_[0]) {
            case "January" { return 1 }
            case "February" { return 2 }
            case "March" { return 3 }
            case "April" { return 4 }
            case "May" { return 5 }
            case "June" { return 6 }
            case "July" { return 7 }
            case "August" { return 8 }
            case "September" { return 9 }
            case "October" { return 10 }
            case "November" { return 11}
            case "December" { return 12 }
        }
}
```

Comment: A `foreach` block of 184 lines is a nightmare to read and debug. please refactor that to functions. And add comments. BTW, you should add a  `close` for the  `open FILE, $file;` line.Also you are forgetting to close GOALCSV ... but surely that's not the problem.

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to read this.  If you want help, you'll probably need to do some work to isolate the problem yourself.

Comment: The standard month name translation idiom is simply `$month=qw(Jan Feb Mar ...); print $month[4];` and a simple hash to do the opposite; `%mo = map { $_ => $month[$_]+1 } 0..$#month;`

Comment: Similarly the team name lookup would be a lot neater using just a hash.

Comment: Why do you use a hash for `%xlateNum2Text`, instead of an array? Also why don't you use a hash for `rightTeamName` and `monthConvert` ( `my %right_team_name = ( 'QPR' => 'Queens Park Rangers', ... ); sub right_team_name{ return $right_team_name{$_[0]} || $_[0] }`? Especially since [Switch](http://p3rl.org/Switch) is not recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML::Query uses HTML::Element and HTML::TreeBuilder to model the nodes of your document. The nodes are connected in a complex way that makes it impossible for the Perl garbage collector to clean up the nodes. Therefore, you either have to

- Assert that you have a version of HTML::Element that can use weak references. These do not prevent garbage collection. A `use HTML::TreeBuilder 5 -weak` should do the trick.
- Call `delete` on any result of the `query` method.

See the documentation (e.g. in [HTML::Element](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aElement#Weak-References)) for more information.

Below is a cleaned up version of your script that tries to reduce code duplication (there were clear signs of copy & paste in the original code).  It still isn't beautiful, and some WTFs remain, but it should be an improvement to maintainability. Notably, I don't know what on earth the 12th column of `@allinfogoals` is (in the sort), or why the CSV is emitted in this rather weird way (we already know the index of the `for:` column (→ 2), so we don't have match every column against the expected value).

A hint for understanding some missing if-elses: When a string doesn't contain a certain substring, then the return value of splitting the string on that substring is equal to the original string. As code:

```
use Test::More;
my ($string, $substring) = ("foo+bar", "-"); # try it yourself!
my ($split) = split /\Q$substring\E/, $string;
if (-1 == index $string, $substring) {
  is $split, $string;
} else {
  isnt $split, $string;
}
done_testing;
```

Here is the cleaned up version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder 5 -weak;
use HTML::Query;

my $dir = '/home/mark/Documents/Perl/garchivesfiles/completeresults';

opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Can't open $dir: $!";

while (my $filename = readdir $dh) {
    next if $filename =~ /^\./;
    my $q = HTML::Query->new(file => "$dir/$filename");

    my $homescore = $q->query("span.homeScore")->first->as_text;
    my $awayscore = $q->query("span.awayScore")->first->as_text;

    my $hometeam = correctTeamName($q->query("table.teaminfo td.home span")->first->as_text);
    my $awayteam = correctTeamName($q->query("table.teaminfo td.away span")->first->as_text);

    my @allinfogoals;

    if($homescore ne "0" || $awayscore ne "0") {

        my ($fixtureinfo_span) = $q->query("p.fixtureinfo span");
        my (undef, $day, $month, $year) = split ' ', $fixtureinfo_span->as_text;
        my $mysqldate = sprintf '%04d-%02d-%02d', $year, monthConvert($month), $day;

        my ($fixtureinfo) = $q->query('p.fixtureinfo');
        my (undef, $fixtureinfostring) = split / \| /, $fixtureinfo->as_text;

        for my $goal_list (
            [$hometeam, $awayteam, [$q->query("div.home ul li")->as_text]],
            [$awayteam, $hometeam, [$q->query("div.away ul li")->as_text]]
        ) {
            my ($thisteam, $otherteam, $goalstotal) = @$goal_list;
            for my $goal (@$goalstotal) {
                $goal =~ s/\)//g;
                my ($tempcomponent_1, $tempcomponent) = split / \(/, $goal;

                for my $individmultgoal (split/,/, $tempcomponent) {
                    next if -1 != index $individmultgoal, 'OG';
                    $individmultgoal =~ s/Pen//g;
                    $individmultgoal =~ s/ //g;
                    my @timesplit = 
                        (index($individmultgoal, "+") != -1)
                        ? (split /\+/, $individmultgoal)
                        : ($individmultgoal, 0);
                    push @allinfogoals, [
                        $tempcomponent_1,
                        $timesplit[0],
                        "for:$thisteam",
                        $otherteam,
                        $day,
                        $month,
                        $year,
                        $fixtureinfostring,
                        "Barclays Premier League",
                        monthConvert($month),
                        $mysqldate,
                        $timesplit[1],
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        @allinfogoals = sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[12] <=> $b->[12] } @allinfogoals;

        open my $GOALCSV, '>>', 'goalcsv.txt' or die "Can't open goalcsv.txt: $!";

        my $print_both = sub {
            print {$GOALCSV} @_;
            print            @_;
        };

        my $homegoalcount = 0;
        my $awaygoalcount = 0;

        for my $row (@allinfogoals){
            for my $val(@$row){
                if($val eq "for:$hometeam") {
                    $homegoalcount++;
                    $print_both->("$val,$homegoalcount,$awaygoalcount,true,");
                } elsif($val eq "for:$awayteam") {
                    $awaygoalcount++;
                    $print_both->("$val,$awaygoalcount,$homegoalcount,false,");
                } else {
                    $print_both->("$val,");
                }
            }
            $print_both->("\n");
        }
    }
}

closedir $dh;

sub correctTeamName{
    my %teamnames = (
        "Nott'm Forest" => "Nottingham Forest",
        "QPR"           => "Queens Park Rangers",
        "Southampton"   => "Southampton FC",
        "Norwich"       => "Norwich City",
        "Tottenham"     => "Tottenham Hotspur",
        "Leeds"         => "Leeds United",
        "Middlesbrough" => "Middlesbrough FC",
        "Chelsea"       => "Chelsea FC",
        "Arsenal"       => "Arsenal FC",
        "Oldham"        => "Oldham Athletic",
        "Ipswich"       => "Ipswich Town",
        "Man Utd"       => "Manchester United",
        "Man City"      => "Manchester City",
        "Sheffield Wed" => "Sheffield Wednesday",
        "Man City"      => "Manchester City",
        "Blackburn"     => "Blackburn Rovers",
        "Wimbledon"     => "AFC Wimbledon",
        "Liverpool"     => "Liverpool FC",
        "Coventry"      => "Coventry City",
    );
    return exists $teamnames{$_[1]} ? $teamnames{$_[1]} : $_[0];
}

sub monthConvert{
    my $i = 1;
    my %months = map { $_ => $i++ } qw/
        January February    March
        April   May         June
        July    August      September
        October November    December
    /;
    exists $months{$_[0]} or die "Unknown month name $_[0]";
    return $months{$_[0]};
}
```

Note: Code is untested, as no example files were provided. At least it compiles.

Comment: I hate to just take the code and use it, but it worked perfectly. Most of the problems stem from me just trying out Perl to see how it looks without really learning it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

most likely one or more of your files is very large.

print out the names of the files as you go through them.   you'll see your code breaks on one of them each time.